# Order of Integration in Divergent Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, improper-integrals, laurent-series

I'm looking to compute the integral
$$I = \int_0^\infty dy \, \sinh^{d-2 \epsilon -1} y $$ as a Laurent series in $\epsilon$. (For those who are familiar with it, this is related to dimensional regularization.)

My attempt so far has been to use the familiar identity for the $\Gamma$ function,
$$\alpha^{-s} \Gamma(s) = \int_0^\infty dx x^{s-1} e^{-\alpha x}.$$

From here, I can do the typical thing where I write
$$I = \frac{1}{\Gamma(1+2\epsilon -d)} \int_0^\infty dy \, \int_0^\infty dx\, x^{2\epsilon-1} e^{-x\sinh(y)}.$$

So far, these expressions should agree in the limit where $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ for all positive integer $d$. Now, the trouble comes when I do the typical trick of reordering the integral to instead integrate with respect to $y$ first, yielding

$$I = \frac{1}{\Gamma(1+2\epsilon -d)} \int_0^\infty dx \, x^{2\epsilon-1} \int_0^\infty dy\,  e^{-x\sinh(y)}.$$

I've used Maple to compute the $y$ integral, obtaining
$$\int_0^\infty dy\,  e^{-x\sinh(y)} = \frac{\pi}{2} \left[H_0(x) - Y_0(x) \right]$$
where $H_0(x)$ is the Struve function of order $0$ and $Y_0(x)$ is the Bessel function of the second kind (of order $0$).

From here, Maple can (again) integrate directly the next integral. I won't bore you with the details, but the bottom line is that for even $d$,
$$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} I = \text{finite!}$$.

Now one can easily see that the original integral is clearly divergent for any integer $d>1$.

So what went wrong here? I know that I am playing with fire by working with divergent quantities and rearranging integrals all over the place (don't hate me, I'm a physicist!), but this seems bizarre to say the least.

Does anyone have any intuition as to why this may be going wrong, and how I can still do this type of manipulation legally?

Alternatively, does anyone have any idea how to explicitly compute the integral $I$ without resorting to the $\Gamma$ function trick?

Comment: Well, the first problem is that the $\Gamma$ identity only works for positive $s$.

Comment: Haven't followed your calculation in detail, but it's not uncommon to get finite expressions for divergent quantities when doing dimensional regularization. It is a form of regularization by analytic continuation... and what's the most famous analytic continuation? The zeta function continuation to $s=-1,$ where you get a finite answer for a manifestly divergent sum. The only reason we often see divergences in $\epsilon$ in standard calculations involving the Gamma function is cause we are expanding about one of its poles at negative ints. Sometimes, say in $d=3,$ we get finite results too.

Comment: @Chappers Any suggestions how to analytically continue the identity, then? The identity is "true" for negative integers $s$, so there may be hope?

Comment: The correct analytic continuation is $\alpha^{-s}\Gamma(s) = \int_0^{\infty} x^{s-1} (e^{-\alpha x}-\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(\alpha x)^k}{k!}) \, dx,  $ obtained by integrating by parts; this converges when $-(n+1)<\Re(s)<-n$. But you're likely better off substituting $y=e^{-2x}$ in the original integral, which just turns the integral into a beta-function, albeit one with exactly the same convergence issues.